# hevc frame level bit allocation

Tags: c++, algorithm, hevc, rdo

Hi I am working on HEVC standard using HM Reference code Version 13.0. I'm working on a new algorithm for frame level bit allocation and in order to estimate some parameters I need to know the number of bit used by the encoder for the luma component. To be more precise, for each block I want to know the actual number of bit used to encode the luma component of the block after the quantization (or after the entropy coding, if it's simpler).
Thanks a lot